# Suggestion of articles/books/search terms to set up end-to-end build, deployment and test processes in .net

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, agile

I've been googling a lot lately trying to find articles, books , or even the correct search terms on more 'agile' web application infrastructure/setups but dont think im currently searching the right terms!

Im looking for an overview of best practices that will take me through how i should set things up with regards to things like automating builds, automating deployment to staging and production, continuous integration, versioning, testing etc. etc.

Im working on a pretty complex online store using .net and have so far started getting to grips with using MSBuild to control my builds and TeamCity running builds after commits to GitHub.

I have been working through the 'Inside MSBuild' book which is pretty cool and also a book on brownfield applications which is actually equally useful for a fresh project.

So im getting to grips with individual pieces but really want some concrete processes to follow.

Any help, greatly appreciated as Im fed up with aimlessly googling!

Sam : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track with TeamCity in my opinion; we tried CruiseControl.NET first and found it required more XML-editing.

There is a book on [Continuous Integration in .NET](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1935182552); I have not read it.

There is also [Continuous Delivery: Reliable Software Releases through Build, Test, and Deployment Automation](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321601912) - I have not read that either, but Fowler-approved books are generally excellent. There's also an older book in the series on [Continuous Integration](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321336380).

If TeamCity is working for you, I'd suggest studying testing first. One of the major values in continuous integration is automated test-running. I **can** recommend a book on that: [The Art of Unit Testing with Examples in .NET](http://www.manning.com/osherove/).

My personal opinion is that MSBuild scripts are best left to Visual Studio. If having TeamCity run solutions and NUnit/xUnit tests proves insufficient, you might take a look at [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/). While it is XML-based, I find it easier to understand than MSBuild.

Comment: Thanks very much, the recommendations look great especially the first two, so much i think im gonna have to hit up the bookshop in the morning!  I actually browsed past the first book in a shop the other day but didnt look inside as i figured it was just about CI servers but I can see from Amazon it covers a lot of the stuff Im after.  The continuous delivery book also seems to get down to guts about deployment which is great for me, exactly what I need.

Comment: The second book has a chapter about not using build tools to control your build so maybe I'll be able to ditch MSBuild, we'll see! Thanks again